# how to open a browser passing parameter a html code

Tags: wpf, httpwebrequest, browser, webrequest

My `WebRequest` returns an html code for the page I want to show.

How can I show it using a html code returned from my WPF? how can I "create" a page using just returned html code ?
And how can I focus a browser when it is open?

Plz, some example will be fine. thanks

Comment: You want to display the html page in a wpf application?

Answer (score 1):

You can display an `HTML` web page from a `string` variable in a `WebBrowser` control *in a WPF application* using the `NavigateToString` method:

The XAML:

```
<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" />
```

The code:

```
webBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlPageAsAString);
webBrowser.Focus();
```

Please take a look at the [WebBrowser.NavigateToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) page for more information.